# Does allowing $\forall$ to be a relation symbol cause conflicts?

Tags: soft-question, first-order-logic

This is a very silly question, and strictly speaking not a mathematical one. Feel free to downvote.

> **Definition.** We fix a *signature* $S$, which is a set that may contain relation symbols, function symbols, and constant symbols. We assume that function symbols and relations symbols have an arity $\geq 1$. A string over the alphabet $\{\forall, \exists, (, ), \land, \lor, \rightarrow, \neg, =\}\cup S\cup \{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n, \dots\}$ (the symbols $v_i$ are assumed to be variables) is said to be a *first-order formula* if and only if this can be shown with the following rules:
>
> 1. If $R$ is an $n$-ary relation symbol, and $x_1, \dots, x_n$ are [terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Terms), then $Rx_1 \dots x_n$ is a formula. Also, if $x,y$ are terms, then $x=y$ should be a formula.
> 2. If $\phi$ and $\psi$ are two formulas, then $(\phi)\land(\psi)$, $(\phi)\lor(\psi)$, $(\phi)\rightarrow(\psi)$, and $\neg(\phi)$ are formulas.
> 3. If $\phi$ is a formula, and $v$ is a variable, then $\forall v\phi$ and $\exists v\phi$ are formulas.

Some authors require the sets $\{\forall, \exists, (, ), \land, \lor, \rightarrow, \neg, =\}$, $S$, and $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n, \dots\}$ to be pairwise disjoint *in order to prohibit conflicts*. Is this requirement necessary? Can there really occur situations where the readability isn't unique if one, say, allows that $\forall$ can be a relation symbol? One could think that based on the position of $\forall$ in a formula one can always reconstruct if $\forall$ acts there as a quantifier or a relation symbol.

Edit: Allowing $\forall$ to be a relation symbol is just an example. One could also ask whether it causes readability conflicts if one allows $($ to be a variable, or whatever stupid example one might come up with.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the selection of appropriate tags.

Comment: if everything is $($ the formula $(((((($ is correct but you don't know how to interpret it (sorry but you asked for stupid examples ...)

Comment: @wece: Mhm, I would not allow every symbol to be $($, even if I ask about what happens if the sets {∀,∃,(,),∧,∨,→,¬,=}, S, and  {v1,v2,…,vn,…} are not disjoint. For example, I regard ∀,∃,(,),∧,∨,→,¬,= and v1,v2,…,vn,… as once and for all fixed distinct symbols.

Comment: I realize that it's hard to explain what I mean. Let's consider your specific example. You are considering the sentence ((((((. Are you regarding this as an atomic formula (that is, a formula of the form x = y or Rx_1…x_n) or a disjunction, conjunction, implication or quantified statement? When you are regarding this for example as a conjunction where "(" should be the symbol ∧, then this is something I wouldn't allow, since I assume that ∧ is not the same as (.

Comment: Do you think at it as a one-place relation symbol (i.e. $\forall x$ is like $Px$) ? If so, I think we may have problems : today $\forall x \forall x Px$ is (menaingless but) formally correct; with the "double use" it will be wrong (like e.g. $\forall x QxPx$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x$ is both a variable and a $2$-ary relation, and suppose $=$ is also a variable. Then

> $x=y$

would mean both that $=$ and $y$ had the property $x$, and that $x$ was equal to $y$.